# Why does GAE skip changed files when deploying?

Tags: google-app-engine, app.yaml

Often when I make a local change to a .js or .css file and then I deploy the app the files are skipped.  What's going on?

For example, let's say I edit:

`public_html/www/account/dashboard/dashboard.css`

When I deploy I see this in my log:

```
`Skipping upload of [public_html/www/account/dashboard/dashboard.css]
```

Here is the skip_files rule in my app.yaml

```
skip_files:
    - ^(.*/)?#.*#$
    - ^(.*/)?.*~$
    - ^(.*/)?.*\.py[co]$
    - ^(.*/)?.*/RCS/.*$
    - ^(.*/)?\..*$
    - ^.*node_modules(/.*)?
    - ^data/.*$
    - ^public_html/data/.*$
```

And not sure if this is related but here is a static_files rule for making my css application_readable:

```
- url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|jpeg|js|html|css|json|tpl))$
  static_files: public_html/www/\1
  upload: public_html/www/.*\.(gif|png|jpg|js|html|css|json|tpl)$
  application_readable: true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found an answer in the docs.  It has to do with static file cache expiration.  It sounds like there is no way to immediately clear out static file caches.  The best thing to do is to set the default_expiration to a short time period, mine was set to 7 days.

Here is a link to the docs:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#static_cache_expiration

Here is an explanation from the docs

> The expiration time will be sent in the Cache-Control and Expires HTTP
>   response headers, and therefore, the files are likely to be cached by
>   the user's browser, as well as by intermediate caching proxy servers
>   such as Internet Service Providers. After a file is transmitted with a
>   given expiration time, there is generally no way to clear it out of
>   intermediate caches, even if the user clears their own browser cache.
>   Re-deploying a new version of the app will not reset any caches.
>   Therefore, if you ever plan to modify a static file, it should have a
>   short (less than one hour) expiration time. In most cases, the default
>   10-minute expiration time is appropriate.